# Looping over file contents with the for command has issue with the last item

Tags: windows, batch-file, cmd, eol

I have a `filename.txt` with the following contents:

```
HEL50-C2
DEN50-C1
SFO5-C3
BRU50-C1
SCL50-C1
```

I have a program which runs this:

```
FOR /F  %%G IN (filename.txt) DO  (ECHO %%G)
```

But when I run it, it only returns a modified version of the last line of the file:

```
SCL50-C1C1
```

What am I missing?  I think it has something to do with the hyphens, but I'm not sure how to account for them.

Comment: Possibly delayed expansion.  Try losing the brackets in the echo part

Comment: No, @cup, delayed expansion can't be an issue here since it doesn't apply to `for` meta-variables; and the parentheses don't harm here either…

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my file had only carriage return (\r) at the end of each line. When I added carriage return and line feed (\r\n) the script ran fine.